# In IKEA kitchen marketing, what does 'kvm' mean?

Tags: kitchens

[This page](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/categories/departments/metod_kitchen/roomset/20143_nkro17a/) advertises an IKEA demo kitchen. In the panel just below the main image, it quotes the following:

> £3,060 without appliances
>
> 12 kvm

What does 'kvm' mean? Is this a Swedish name for a unit of measure that they didn't realise they should translate? I can't find any mention of it besides the adverts themselves, and googling a number of permutations of 'kvm ikea kitchen' doesn't yield anything that looks useful.

**edit:** As of July 2015; the linked page still exists, but has been updated to read 'sqm' which English-speakers would readily interpret the way it is intended - 'square metres'.

Comment: It seems related to the size of the kitchen. The equivalent Canadian gallery is at http://www.ikea.com/ca/en/catalog/categories/departments/kitchen/roomset/20132_kiro02h/ (with different kitchens) and it says things like 10' x 10' in that same place on the page.

Comment: It stands for kvadratmeter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is short for m^2 which stands for *kvadratmeter*. This is the total area the kitchen will cover. The two terms are user interchangeably in the Swedish language. [Wikipedia article (in Swedish)](http://sv.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areaenhet)

Comment: Thanks. I suspected it might be, but it'd really be helpful for them to say so (or else, translate their pages appropriately).

Comment: They've made an advertising shtick out of not translating/transliterating; I'm not surprised they do so even when they shouldn't,